# Upload progress on a proxied request to aws s3

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, upload

I am trying to figure out how the get the upload progress of the following situation:

```
node.js client uploads to -> node.js server which uploads to -> aws s3
```

My node.js client receives his response when the node.js server is done uploading to s3. (basically, I dont call res.end() from the node.js server until the s3 upload has completed)

I can get the upload progress from my client to server upload by checking the npm-module-request's `r.req.connection.bytesWritten` but I am having trouble figuring out how to get the progress from my server to s3. I am really lost on how to do this.

Is there a way to somehow stream the progress from my server to s3 inside the client to server request?

thank you in advance